# Angular2 Grid error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a complete newbie to anything related Javascript, but I need to develop a rich webapp and I trying to learn Angular2 with Typescript.

I am using Angular 2 (version 2.4.2)

I am attempting to use the [angular2-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-grid) plugin

When I try to install it, I get this worrying result:

```
$ npm install angular2-grid
first-app@0.0.0 /home/nick/dev/angular2/first-app
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.2
└── angular2-grid@0.11.2 

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN angular2-grid@0.11.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

If I ignore the warmings and then try and use it anyway, I get this error in the browser log:

```
Can't bind to 'ngGrid' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgGridModule } from 'angular2-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mygrid',
  template: `
  <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <div class="grid" [ngGrid]="{\'max_cols\': 6, \'auto_resize\': true}">
    <div class="grid-item" [ngGridItem]="{\'sizex\': 2, \'sizey\': 3}">
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class MygridComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Is the error in the log related to the warning when I tried to install the angular2-grid? Did it not install? How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround until the problem is fixed:
We inject the components in our src folder like it is our components (look like vendoring).

- Create an angular2-grid folder somewhere in your src folder (for example, I placed it in src/app) and copy paste NgGrid.css, main.ts + components / directives / modules / interfaces folders
- Import it in your app module : `import { NgGridModule } from './angular2-grid/modules/NgGrid.module';`  (The path is relative of where you put your angular2grid, here is on the root of app folder)
- Use this lib as described in the repo's readme but adapt your dependency path (example in `app.component.ts`: `import { NgGridConfig, NgGridItemConfig } from "./angular2-grid/interfaces/INgGrid";`

We do it for the project: [project with angular2-grid](https://github.com/flightwatching/svg-animator/commits/develop)

Answer (score -1):

Did you import the "NgGridModule" in your root module like below example?

```
            //Root module
            import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
            import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
            import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser'
            import { MygridComponent  } from './mygridcomponent'
            import { NgGridModule } from 'angular2-grid';

            @NgModule({
              imports: [ BrowserModule, NgGridModule ],
              declarations: [ MygridComponent  ],
              providers: [],
              bootstrap: [ MygridComponent  ]
            })

            export class AppModule { }


            // main entry point
            import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
            import { AppModule } from './app.module';

            platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: I tried but i got the error ERROR in NgGridModule is not an NgModule. The repsonse to this issue [issue 179](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid/issues/179) seem's to not solve the problem